# Program to draw electron dot formulas

Tags: windows, macos

Is there any program that supports drawing electron dot formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googleing for "programs for drawing lewis structures" brought up the following:

http://www.chemaxon.com/download/marvin/

http://www.cambridgesoft.com/software/ChemDraw/

http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/ <- Can do Lewis Structures with a little work.